# How to make part of the loop execute only in one of the workers?

Tags: c, multithreading, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a loop opening multiple connections to a remote SFTP-server. Each session needs to verify the remote host's key, but the existing list of keys only needs to be loaded *once*.

The libssh2 API I'm using requires an existing session for loading the list, so I cannot read it *before* entering into the loop -- as the sessions are initialized inside it.

Are there pragmas, that'll allow me to:

1. Make one of threads -- I don't care, which one -- load the `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.
2. Cause all of the other threads to *wait* for that lucky one to do it?

I tried:

```
    #pragma omp for
    for (i = 0; i < jobs; i++) {
        sessions[i] = libssh2_session_init();
        ...
        #pragma omp task
        {
            known = load_known_hosts(sessions[i], ...);
        }

        #pragma omp taskwait
        check_known_hosts(known, ...);
        ...
    }
```

This compiles, but does not work as intended -- the list is still uninitialized, when the `check_known_hosts()` tries to use it.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is the following (similar to what @[deamcrash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72725330/1366871) suggested, but initialization can also be done in parallel)

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    ...
    #pragma omp for
    for (i = 0; i < jobs; i++) {
    //initialization in parallel
    sessions[i] = libssh2_session_init();
    ...
    }

    #pragma omp single
    {
        // work done by a single thread 
        known = load_known_hosts(...);
        ...
    }

    #pragma omp for
    for (i = 0; i < jobs; i++) {
        //other parallel work
        check_known_hosts(known, ...);
        ....
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I actually like yours a bit more, for some reason I was under the impression that session[0] would have to be init and load_known_hosts then the others.

Comment: So you'd split my loop into two -- one to initialize all sessions, and the second one to start using them, with the loading of known hosts' database in between. Ok, that'd work... Still, I'm surprised, one cannot mark a section of a parallelized loop execute exactly _once_ -- by whatever thread arrives to it first.

Comment: The problem is that you need a *synchronization point* at which threads in a parallel region will wait until your "marked" section finishes.  In OpenMP you can achieve this by using (an implicit or explicit) barrier after it, but a barrier cannot be used inside a work-sharing loop.

Answer (score 1):

Without more context I would go for:

```
    #pragma omp single
    {
        sessions[0] = libssh2_session_init();
        ...
        known = load_known_hosts(sessions[0], ...);
        ...
        check_known_hosts(known, ...);
        ...
    }

    #pragma omp for
    for (i = 1; i < jobs; i++) {
        sessions[i] = libssh2_session_init();
        ...
        check_known_hosts(known, ...);
        ...
    }
```

I would extract the first iteration out of the loop, executed before the parallel loop, and then execute the loop. To make it clean you could extract a method out of the code being executed in each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

My quick and dirty "solution" was to load the list for the first job only -- and make other workers spin, if they arrive to this point before the job-0 does:

```
    if (i == 0) {
        known = load_known_hosts(sessions[0], ...);
        if (known == NULL)
            errx(EX_SOFTWARE, "Couldn't load known hosts");
    } else while (known == NULL)
        pthread_yield();
```

I'm sure, there is a way to do this properly -- with OpenMP pragmas -- so awaiting the proper answer.

Comment: Make sure that "known" is change atomically otherwise you can get race-conditions.

Comment: Besides race conditions your code assumes that OpenMP is based on pthreads, which is not required by the standard.

Comment: `known` is a pointer, assigned, when the loading is done -- what's the race? Yes, I know about pthreads, that's why I'm calling this "dirty" -- and would like a proper solution using OpenMP pragmas. Is there one?